# Is what has been deduced from this piece of information correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following piece of information is a part of "constituent assembly debates" of Indian Constituent Assembly given in my book:

> But the point is to see when and how are you going to apply that challenge. Well, Sir, the point is that the imposition is here right now. **Not only has the British Plan made any future Constitution... dependent on a treaty satisfactory to the Britisher but it suggests that for every little difference you will have to run to the Federal Court or dance attendance there in England**.

And there was a [question](https://www.zigya.com/amp/study/book?class=12&board=CBSE&subject=History&book=Themes+in+Indian+History+III&chapter=Framing+The+Constitution&q_type=LAT&q_topic=The+Powers+of+the+State+&question_id=HSEN12115975) I found related to this paragraph online. And one of the several questions was:

> Explain why Somnath (the one of whom these words are) feels that the absence of constitution will mean dependence on the British.

I don't think, in any measure, it can be deduced from that bit of speech that there was as absence of constitution. In fact, it states that any future constitution has been made. Am I right?

I know ELL would be better place to ask this question but I didn't get any response there.

Comment: A "any future Constitution" is not a current Constitution. Pay close attention to what *any* means.

Comment: But the "not only.... but" phrasing of the sentence suggests that alongside the making of the constitution there is an another thing.

Comment: Not only will any possible future Constitution that India writes be subject to British approval before it goes into effect, but also any time India wants to modify the Constitution after it is first written. they will have to again ask the British for approval ("dance attendance there in England").

Comment: You are quite correct, kelvin. There is no mention of a present constitution that might well be in force. '... any future [c]onstitution' is ambiguous. **However** (and this is off-topic) whether or not there was a constitution at the time is a matter of historical fact.

Comment: It sounds to me as though it is saying that it is the "British plan" which has made "any future Constitution...dependent on a treaty satisfactory to the British". There seem to be some words missed out replaced by "...". What do they say? It is difficult to conclude much without further information. What was "the British plan"?

Comment: The title needs to be fixed.  Not sure what it is supposed to say, but “that’s not it. “

Comment: @aparente001-  Haha. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot conclude from the quoted paragraph that there was no constitution at the time.  There could have been a constitution that may have been later replaced, for example.

However, the question does not require you to make any such conclusion.  You are probably expected to know this through other study.  *Given* that there was no constitution at the time, explain why Somnath thinks its absence implies a dependence on the British.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to draw the desired inference (absence of a constitution) either, from the excerpt you posted here, because "any future Constitution" might mean that this was going to be the first constitution, but it might also mean that there already was a constitution, which might get revamped in the future.

However, there is an important clue in the next sentence.  Here is your portion of the excerpt, in gray, followed by a little bit more, not in gray.  I will put the clue in boldface.

> `Not only has the British Plan made any future Constitution... dependent on a treaty satisfactory to the Britisher but it suggests that for every little difference you will have to run to the Federal Court or dance attendance there in England;` or to call on the British Prime Minister Clement Attlee or someone else. Not only is it a fact that **this Constituent Assembly**, whatever plans we may be hatching, we are under the shadow of British guns, British Army, their economic and financial stranglehold — which means that the final power is still in the British hands and the question of power has not yet been finally decided, which means the future is not yet completely in our hands.

A "constituent assembly" is defined in Wikipedia as

> a body or assembly of popularly elected representatives composed for the purpose of drafting or adopting a constitutional-type document.

Thus, it is the phrase starting with "Not only is it a fact" which tells us the passage was written in a historical moment in which there was no constitution in place.